# Pull back of ample divisor by a birational morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a normal projective variety of Picard number one. Let $\pi: Y \to X$ be a resolution of singularity of $X$ and $A$ is the ample generator of $\text{Pic}(X)$.  Then $\pi^*A$ is nef but not ample.

Question: Does there exist a nef divisor $E$ on $Y$ such that $\pi^*A + E$ is ample ?

Comment: In general, no. In https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=914085 the resolutions of the Segre cubic are described, and some of them are non-projective, thus they admit no ample line bundles whatsoever.

Comment: If $Y$ is projective then yes --- you can take any ample divisor on $Y$ as $E$.